# How do I use the command line to search for multiple characters at the same time?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, dir

Write a DOS command to display all files on drive C: whose filenames are 7 characters long and begins with the letters CHAR.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Powershell:

```
dir C:\ |?{$_.basename-match"^CHAR.{3}$"}
```